# AutoMapper with a list data from IDataReader

Tags: c#, automapper, idatareader

```
using (IDataReader dr = DatabaseContext.ExecuteReader(command))
        {
            if (dr.Read())
            {
                AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<IDataReader, ProductModel>();
                return AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<IDataReader, IList<ProductModel>>(dr);
            }
            return null;
        }
```

if dr has **only one row** -> error: *threw an exception of type 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException'*

if dr has **more than** one row, it run **ok**.

any help?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that Automapper is calling Read() as well - so is trying to always look at the second record onwards. If you think about it if you have 1000 rows in the reader - how is AutoMapper going to convert that to a list without iterating through them all calling Read()?

Change your line to call HasRows

e.g.

```
using (IDataReader dr = DatabaseContext.ExecuteReader(command))
    {
        if (dr.HasRows)
        {
            AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<IDataReader, ProductModel>();
            return AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<IDataReader, IList<ProductModel>>(dr);
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Comment: thank, you're but... AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<IDataReader, IList<ProductModel>>(); or AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<IDataReader, ProductModel>(); is right? I see both of them work okey!

Comment: I always prefer to be more explicit so IList<ProductModel>. It probably does some magic so that it doesn't matter internally.

Comment: It throws an error saying it doesn't like `IList`. And It returns empty list to me, when i specify `List` instead of `IList`.

Answer (score -4):

Add AutoMapper.Net4 and add the mappers ahead of CreateMap as below:

```
    MapperRegistry.Mappers.Add(new DataReaderMapper());
    MapperRegistry.Mappers.Add(new NameValueCollectionMapper());
    MapperRegistry.Mappers.Add(new HashSetMapper());
    MapperRegistry.Mappers.Add(new ListSourceMapper());
    MapperRegistry.Mappers.Add(new TypeConverterMapper());
```

Comment: How is this the answer to the original question?