# AutoMapper.Data error when mapping

Tags: c#, sql-server, automapper, idatareader, automapper-4

I am using automapper v4.1.1 and automapper.data1.0.0.beta 1. I have console app and my mapping code looks like:

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg => {
            MapperRegistry.Mappers.Add(new DataReaderMapper {YieldReturnEnabled = true}
            );

            cfg.CreateMap<IDataRecord, AircraftDetails>();

        });
```

And my db call code and mapping looks like

```
var aircraft=new AircraftDetails();         
        using (SqlConnection connection =
               new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[_connectionString].ConnectionString))
        {
            SqlCommand command =
                new SqlCommand(storedProcedureAsString, connection);


            command.AddInputParameters(new {a=aircraftId});

            connection.Open();

            SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            if (reader.HasRows)
            {

               var res = Mapper.Map<IDataReader, IEnumerable<AircraftDetails>>(reader);

                aircraft = res.FirstOrDefault();
            }

        }

        return aircraft;
```

When i run this code i get error:

> Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.
>      at DynamicCreate(IDataRecord )
>      at AutoMapper.Data.DataReaderMapper.d__10.MoveNext()
>      at System.Linq.Enumerable.d__94`1.MoveNext()
>      at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Cheers

Ismail

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but may be you should create mapping not for IDataRecord, but for IDataReader:

```
cfg.CreateMap<IDataReader, IEnumerable<AircraftDetails>>();
```

Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6873822/automapper-with-a-list-data-from-idatareader)

Comment: Hi kudrya, tried that no joy.  I just followed example in automapper.data test and thats how its done see https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.Data/blob/master/AutoMapper.Data.Tests/DataReaderMapping.cs  test When_mapping_a_data_reader_to_a_dto so mapping is IDataRecord but in map IDataReader kind of makes sense as a read on IDataReader gives you IDataRecord.

Comment: Hm, and what about `cfg.AddMemberConfiguration().AddMember<DataRecordMemberConfiguration>();` in your configuration section?

Comment: kudrya, not tried that as i then decided to use something else as i am pressed for time so i went with https://github.com/sixeyed/projects/tree/master/Sixeyed.Mapping which works.  I may try and revisit if i get time. Many thanks for you help.